# Using Ajax with a php site

Tags: php, ajax, xml

So I have a website that has three forms for adding data into my database and everytime I submit a form the page refreshes, I heard that I should use AJAX to do it without the page refreshing it self. Could anybody point me what should I use?

Comment: Yes, AJAX is what you should use for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo example for adding data to database using AJAX.

```html
form.php


<html>
<head>
    <title>Php submit for using Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="number" name="contact"><br>
        <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'post.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</html>


post.php



<?php

//incluce db connection file

if(isset($_POST["name"]) || isset($_POST["email"]) || isset($_POST["contact"])) {
    
    //Data Insert Login Here

    echo 'response here';//Message to be shown on success
}

?>
```